# Can I place a CPU on an AM4 socket without using the lever?

Tags: heatsink, processor-socket

Sadly, I discovered that my MoBo is faulty and that I need to change it, so I had to remove the heatsink and CPU and send it back - I will get a new MoBo soon.

The original thermal paste on the Arctic Alpine 64 plus heatsink must be pretty strong, for the CPU came away with it. Pins don't look damaged.

Now, I know that the **AM4 socket** works like this: you raise the lever, the plastic grid where the pins go shifts a bit, you place the CPU over it, then you lock the lever again and the CPU falls in place.

Of course, this is not possible if the heatsink is already sticking to the CPU!

**Is it safe to place the CPU down without raising-the-lever-and-getting-the-plastic-grid-to-shift, or should I really remove the thermal paste, buy some new one and re-apply it after socketing the CPU again?**

Comment: Note that the site already hosts a very similar question for AM3 sockets that has been answered by someone talikng about AM2 sockets... here it is: https://superuser.com/q/167220/218040

Answer (score 2):

You probably have way too much thermal paste, or bad paste if you have problems detaching the CPU from the heatsink.

Or as telcoM mentioned, it could have been the optimal amount that made it stick. That would probably be most likely since you used the heat sink with factory applied 'paste'.

I would without doubt separate CPU from heat sink, clean with isopropanol or similar and reapply new thermal paste.

***No, do not try to reattach the CPU without releasing the lever!***

Comment: It's the paste that comes pre-sticked to the heatsink, I did not chose how much to put. I guess I really need to go out and buy thermal paste after all

Comment: Okay, weird that it sticks that much then. I usually take the heat sink off when the CPU is in its socket. The reason I mentioned it is that a lot of people put on 3-4x the amount needed when they apply paste themselves. But either way, the original paste is not really any good. You get the CPU a little cooler by applying the correct amount of quality paste.

Comment: Paradoxically, the problem might be that you've managed to get a perfect thin layer of thermal paste with no air bubbles between two very flat surfaces. If you put just a drop of water between two flat pieces of glass and press them together, it can be surprisingly hard to pull them apart; sliding will work much better. I think we did such an experiment at school, as part of physics lessons on water behavior and surface tension.

Comment: @telcoM Yeah, you might be right on the dot there. I'm no expert in anything, but definitely not in physics :)

Comment: The CPU absolutely **WILL NOT** seat properly in the socket without locking it into place. You must find a way to remove the heatsink in order to properly install the CPU.  Failure to do this will result to damage to the socket, which is not typically covered under warranty, so always take care when installing the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to place the CPU down without raising-the-lever-and-getting-the-plastic-grid-to-shift

No.
The socket with a lever means that it is a [zero insertion force (ZIF) socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force).
You will not be able to properly install and lock the CPU chip in a ZIF socket without first opening the socket (raise the lever).

The best method of separating the heatsink from the CPU chip is by twisting them apart.
Wait until you have a motherboard again.  Open the ZIF socket. Place the CPU chip in the socket, paying attention to the pin alignment.
Apply a *slight* downward force (so that the chip stays in the socket) and a firm, steady twisting force to the heatsink.
The heatsink should break free from the CPU chip.